# Insert image in RMarkdown bash code using RStudio 1.4

Tags: bash, r-markdown

I am trying to create a bash script that loops trough a folder and prints all images.

However the line that should print the image actually doesn't print the image it self, it just prints the text.

````
```{bash echo=FALSE, comment=""}
echo "![$name]($dir/$file)";
```
````

Example output:

> [dog][images/dog.jpg]

What i want is the actual image of the dog:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `results="asis"` to your document.

````
```{bash echo=FALSE, comment="", results="asis"}
echo "![$name]($dir/$file)";
```
````

See more at https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/results-asis.html

(BTW, on my rendering, without `results="asis"`, I see

```r
![](./1RfMf.jpg)
```

In your output the bang `!` is missing.)